# ViewState Variable Reset After Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I've seen this problem a lot, and it's usually because the `ViewState` variables are being evaluated too early in the page lifecycle, or that `EnableViewState` is false, but I've checked for both of these and they are as I'd expect them to be.

My code:

```
public Int32 MyNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["MyNumber"] != null)
        {
            return (Int32)ViewState["MyNumber"];
        }

        return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["MyNumber"] = value;
    }
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        MyNumber = 23;
    }
}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    var numberValue = MyNumber;
}
```

When `OnPreRender` is first called, `numberValue` is 23. Every subsequent call thereafter it's 0. Every time there's a postback it appears to get reset.

**Question**

How do I get the value to persist after a postback?

**What I've Tried**

Bringing the value assignment outside of the check for a postback, but then that defeats the purpose of using `ViewState` in the first place.

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks, edited. I've cut the code right down in an attempt to simplify the question and left 'null' in there (there's nothing else in my code of relevance to this issue anyway).

Comment: there is not any problem with your code. Please check whether `EnableViewState` is false in `web.config`.

Comment: It is not set in web.config (I believe the default is 'true').

Comment: ***Your code is working fine. MyNumber returns 23 in OnPreRender after post back*** It doesn't work only if `<%@ Page EnableViewState="false" %>` which is expected. You can create a new ASP.Net project and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was unaware there was also a `ViewStateMode` that would cause this behaviour if set to `Disabled`, which it was (on the master page).

I've now set that to `Enabled` on my control, and my `ViewState` values persist as I'd hope.

Answer (score -1):

actually you have a missing order in your code block excaution and that makes the value reset by zero everytime between post packs :) ... in the onload Method you wrote the base.onload() method before your code block and that lead the Viewstate to be reset to 0 .

Please fellow that code correction:

```
  public Int32 MyNumber
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["MyNumber"] != null)
                {
                    return (Int32)ViewState["MyNumber"];
                }

                return 0;
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["MyNumber"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(MyNumber.ToString()); // Result now is 23 :)
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {

            // I replaced the order of the code here to get the value of the Viewstate in MyNumber property ..
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                MyNumber = 23;
            }

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

            var numberValue = MyNumber;
        }
```

Good Luck :).